# Why does my if-else logic keeps giving me the else condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

```
int phaseOneResult = phaseOne();
if (phaseOneResult > 0)
{
    Response.Redirect("success.aspx?msg=Details submitted");
}
else
{
    lblPhaseOneErr.Text = "No such record found";
}
```

The code above works for INSERT purpose, but for UPDATE it doesn't work.  Any idea what's wrong with this logic?

This is phaseOne function code

```
private int phaseOne()
{
    int phaseOneResult = 0;
    //Update query here
    //...
    //...
    cmdUpdatePhaseOne.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblPhaseOneErr.Text = "Error submitting: " + ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
}
    return phaseOneResult;
}
```

My data actually DOES updated properly, it just that is doesn't go to the success.aspx page, keeps giving me "No such record found" even though it's a success update

Comment: Can you post the real code? Posted code makes no sense. won't compile!

Comment: int phaseOneResult = 0;, you are giving it value 0, so  fumction will return 0, thats why else part is running.

Comment: In the voice of Homer's insurance assessor: sorry, we can only debug real code, not made-up stuff :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have intialized  phaseOneResult to 0 in the phaseOne method whereas the value is not changed anywhere else thus it always returs zero and else condition only executes.

Comment: Great it works!  i just have to add `phaseOneResult = cmdUpdatePhaseOne.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's not legal code.. but from what you've shown, in phaseOne() you set phaseOneResult to 0 but never set it to anything else.  Thus it always returns 0.

Comment: But why does it work with INSERT query?

Comment: @user3195396 - since that's not legal code, and won't compile, and you don't show us any insert query, how are we supposed to know?  Regardless, if you don't set the phaseOneResult to a value > 0, it will never execute the success.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to

```
private int phaseOne()
{
    int phaseOneResult = 0;

    try
    {

        //Update query here
        //...
        //...
        if(cmdUpdatePhaseOne.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) 
        {
            phaseOneResult = 1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblPhaseOneErr.Text = "Error submitting: " + ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }

    return phaseOneResult;
}
```

This way you will only get a return value of 1 if  the number of rows affected is >0. Otherwise it will return 0.

Comment: What if `ExecuteNonQuery` returns `0`? This method lies

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I can't have my methods telling lies, so I have edited my code as per your comment. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Why not use `phaseOneResult = cmdUpdatePhaseOne.ExecuteNonQuery();` which is more appropriate resulting number of rows affected. :)

Comment: I've just realised I don't need to return 1, but I can't be bothered changing the code.